# Jquery touch enable slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setup a slider, here is jsfiddler `http://jsfiddle.net/zZv5B/`. How can I enable it for touch devises, I want to be able to swipe through panel area to slide next and prev slide. any idea would be really appreciated.

```
var currentIndex = 0;// store current pane index displayed
var ePanes = $('#slider .panel');// store panes collection
function showPane(index){// generic showPane
    // hide current pane
    ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    // set current index : check in panes collection length
    currentIndex = index;
    if(currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = ePanes.length-1;
    else if(currentIndex >= ePanes.length) currentIndex = 0;
    // display pane
    ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    // menu selection
    $('.nav li').removeClass('current').eq(currentIndex).addClass('current');
}
// bind ul links
$('.nav li').click(function(ev){    showPane($(this).index());});
// bind previous & next links
$('.previous').click(function(){    showPane(currentIndex-1);});
$('.next').click(function(){    showPane(currentIndex+1);});
// apply start pane
showPane(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the events ([more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events)) 'touchstart' and 'touchend' and get the start X position and the end x position. You can then compare the two and determine which direction the touch/swipe has happend.

```
var xStart, xEnd;
$('.wrap').on('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {     
    //get start x position
    xStart = e.pageX;
}).on('mouseup touchend', function (e) {
    //get the end x position 
    xEnd = e.originalEvent.pageX;
    if (xStart != xEnd) {
        //swiped
        if (xStart < xEnd) {
            console.log('Right');
            showPane(currentIndex + 1);
        }
        if (xStart > xEnd) {
            console.log('Left');
            showPane(currentIndex - 1);
        }
    }
});
```

example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZv5B/3/) - not sure how browser compatibile this is.

Or you could just use my fave touch enabled slider [swipejs](http://swipejs.com/)

UPDATE:
To make it work correctly for mobile changed xEnd = e.originalEvent.pageX as per @User543294's comment

Also a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZv5B/13/) example to using e.changedTouches[0].pageX as per MDN documetation

Comment: upvoted for doing it the OG way, in spite of the availability of js touch libs.

Comment: @Metagrapher, cheers. Agree, not really worth writing your own code for this, like you say so many libraries. But it is nice to have an idea of how to do it.

Comment: @Kipty, I know there are many libraries, but my aim is to figure-out how can I use the same code and make it work for mobile devises.

Comment: The code is no different on mobile devices than on desktop devices. The difference is ability to use touch, which may exist on some desktop devices, such as MS Surface.  Though my answer does plug right in to your code and uses the click functions. But this is a very nice explanation of what's happening under the covers.

Comment: @kipty you provided exactly what I wanted. I am just checking it on mobile devise actually I am not able to swipe it. on desktop it works perfect.

Comment: @User543294 it's probably a z-index issue. You may be targeting the wrong element.

Comment: @kipto, I got it whats happeneing on mobile xStart and xEnd postions are coming as undefined. for mobile I need to find why this is happening.

Comment: I have to use  xEnd = e.originalEvent.pageX; and BAM it is working now. Thanks alot for your time, really appreciated.

Comment: @User543294 no problem, glad you sorted it. Just had a look at the documentation a bit more and updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zZv5B/13/. Now uses e.changedTouches as per MDN example. The mouse events done have this so I removed them.

Comment: Great, sorry I am having one more issue, how can I restrict it to swipe only on X-axis not y-axis.

Comment: There has to be a difference in the xStart and xEnd positions for it to register. You could add a check to make sure the difference is over 100px or something to make sure that it is really swipe rather than a touch.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [TouchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/). It seems pretty nice, straightforward, and robust.

Maybe something like this?

```
var swipe_obj = { 
    swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) { 
        $(".next").click(); }, 
    swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) { 
        $(".previous").click(); }, 
};

$(".nav li").swipe(swipe_obj);
```

Comment: Or maybe you want to target $(".panel") instead to receive the swipes? I'm not sure what your HTML looks like...

Answer (score 0):

Many touch devices also trigger a click, after a touch event. They usually follow a secuence similar to this: a touch happens, then it will be fired the events "touchstart" -> "touchend" -> "click". Where that last click it's a fake one, and has a huge delay respect native events. But it also works.

So, if efficiencie don't care, don't worry. Your slider will work as you expected it will do.

But if you are interested in to achieve a good performance, I recommend you to handle native events directly. Which can be done using Modernizr dinamic testing.

It's a simple idea:

1 Download and link the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library into your code. 
2 Test at the first line of your code which kind of events you can expect, based on device capabilities. A single line of javascript will be enough:

```
var actualEvent = (Modernizr.touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
```

Extra points if you do this before onReady occurs.

3 Move your current handlers into the "on" form:

```
$('selector').on(actualEvent, callback)
```

Then you will be always handling the real event, not the simulated click fired by tablets and phones. Because the test at the beginning ensures you that "actualEvent" will be "touchstart" just on touchable devices and "click" for the rest.

Of course, you can substitute "touchstar" by the touch event you want. But I think that "touchstar" is the one who best suits your needs.